# Subscribe to an AngularFireObject

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2, angularfire5

I just upgraded to AngularFire2 rc 5.0.

I adapted my code so that it matches the new types and functions but I get the following error when trying to subscribe to a `.object(path)`:

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject'
```

My code below.

**Provider:**

```
getEvent(id: string): AngularFireObject<any> {
    let path = `/events/${id}`;
    return this.af.object(path).valueChanges();
  }
```

**Page:**

```
...
event$: AngularFireObject<any>;
...

// Retrieve event's info
this.event$ = this.eventService.getEvent(this.id);

// Retrieve event's ownership info
let subscription = this.event$.subscribe(event => {
  this.owner$ = this.userService.getUserPublicInfo(event.owner);
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's seems something with app.module, try to see if there's something you have to add to import

Answer (score 0):

You are using `valueChanges()` meaning `getEvent(id: string)` is returning `FirebaseObjectObservable<any>` not `AngularFireObject<any>`. 
Check [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md#retrieve-data).

`AngularFireObject<any>` is returned by `this.af.object(path)`

Change the return type of your function.

```
getEvent(id: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    let path = `/events/${id}`;
    return this.af.object(path).valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: When I try this, and declare `event$: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>` compiler tells me that type FirebaseObjectObservable could not be found (I cannot not import the type... and I read that it is deprecated in 5.0). So what is the best way to handle this? I just want to map and/or subscribe as I was doing before. What's your recommendation?

Comment: In that case try to set return type as Observable<any>

Comment: I have the impression that it is working. The documentation is not that clear on this point. I will resolve the other pending issues and mark as "resolved" if it works. Thx !

Comment: sure :)..glad to help